# Concatenating and Pasting within R console with cat() and paste()

Tags: r, paste, cat

There is likely a very simple solution to my problem, but I seem to be missing it.

I have the following

```
p <- 0.95
```

and I want to display the result in the R console.

I've tried

```
> cat("It is", p*100, "% accurate")

> cat("It is", p*100, paste("%", sep = ""), "accurate")
```

but I get a space between the number and the %

```
> cat("It is", p*100, "% accurate")
The classifier 95 % accurate

> cat("It is", p*100, paste("%", sep = ""), "accurate")
The classifier 95 % accurate
```

The final output should be

```
The classifier is 95% accurate
```

Not sure how to solve this based on reading the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the calculation inside

```
cat("It is", paste0( p*100, "%"), "accurate")
```

`paste0` is shorthand for `sep = ""`.

The glue library is also very nice for this:

```
library(glue)

cat("It is", glue("{p*100}%"), "accurate")
```

Comment: I haven't come across the 'glue' package before. Looks like it will be very handy.

Answer (score 1):

It is `sep` what helps:

```
cat("It is ", p * 100, "% accurate", sep = "")
# It is 95% accurate
```

where `sep` is

> a character vector of strings to append after each element.

with the default value `" "`, hence the space. That's the shortest solution, while alternatively you could indeed use `sprintf` or `paste` as @Hanjo Jo'burg Odendaal suggested.